# php carbon count number of days in a date range

Tags: php, php-carbon

Is there any suitable method in the carbon library which returns the number of days in a date range? I have gone through similar question but they are about total number days between two dates, and not the number of days in a date range.

This is what I'm doing right now.

```
carbon::create($till_date)->diffInDays(carbon::parse($from_date)->subDay())
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply count the diff on days begin:

```
Carbon::create($till_date)->startOfDay()->diffInDays(carbon::parse($from_date)->startOfDay())
```

And just do `+1` if you want to include the last day in the count.